# setting format time to hh:mm:ss:SSS in Streambase

Tags: streambase

In the streambase, there is a time column in the application output view. Time format used is hh:mm:ss as the following link.

http://www.google.co.id/imgres?q=application+output+view+in+streambase&sa=G&biw=1366&bih=705&tbm=isch&tbnid=VxEgT3OgKvwvAM:&imgrefurl=http://www.streambase.com/developers/docs/latest/concepts/applicationoutput.html&docid=KmTtpwz83q4UkM&imgurl=http://www.streambase.com/developers/docs/latest/images/app-output-view-details-pane-as-grid.png&w=483&h=517&ei=a8rJUbKZJ47DkwX7cQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=198&tbnw=185&start=0&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0&tx=150&ty=119

I want to add milliseconds on that view so that the time format from the time column become hh:mm:ss:SSS. My question is how to setting the time format so that can show milliseconds in application output view?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any direct way to add milliseconds to, or otherwise change the output format of, the Time column in the StreamBase Studio Application Output View.

Easiest thing to do is to modify the app to add a field of data type timestamp to the output stream(s) of interest populated by now() as near to the output stream as practical.

Sounds like a fine feature request, and I encourage you to send it to support@tibco.com.

Disclosure/Disclaimer: I am an employee of TIBCO Software, Inc. Opinions expressed here are my own and not TIBCO's.